# Central authentication system for external access

Tags: php, asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I have been looking for a SSO system. So far I have found CAS. I wondered if there are any other solutions, and how stable CAS is?

It would be used for the authentication of many different apps in a large school - so it needs to be stable and reliable. It also needs to be able to be integrated with Active Directory and to work with PHP and ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADFS 2 sounds like a perfect choice for you. It is a free subsystem implementing the WS-Federation SSO protocol. The protocol itself is a standard from the WS-* family which means that you can easily find toolkits to support authentication in any client technology (.NET, PHP, Java).

Technically, ADFS 2 is a web application running on IIS 7.5/Windows Server 2008 and uses Active Directory as a backend.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10909

There are good books on the WS-Federation protocol programming:

Claims Based Identity and Access Control (free ebook)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx

Programming Windows Identity Foundation

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Identity-Foundation-Dev/dp/0735627185](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185)

Comment: I forgot to add that one of the other requirements is that each user should not be required to use a school computer. As most of the users have their own computers, tablets and smartphones it needs to be web-based. Will ADFS work with all browsers, even when they are not part of the Windows domain?

Comment: @Alex. Of course it will. ADFS authentication protocol is based on HTTP and it works in local and wide networks. The ADFS login page is fully customizable so you can for example put a school logo on it.

Comment: Does ADFS simply provide a SAML interface, then I would access it using a SAML library? Or is it its own protocol?

Comment: ADFS uses the passive WS-Federation protocol. It's a standard protocol so that any compliant tool will do.